# Subtract datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to calculate time between two peaks. Let suppose the first peak appear at `31 seconds` and `56 milliseconds`. The second peak appears at `32 second` and `37 milliseconds`. I can simply subtract `32.37-31.56`, which is around `0.8`. What if the first peak appears at `59.32` seconds, and a second peak at `00.32` of the next minute. How can I subtract this?
So I have to incorporate minutes. I used `datetime.now().strftime("%M:%S.%f")` to get minutes, seconds and milliseconds. The output is a string such as `'49:31.566308'`. How I can subtract it from `'49:32.069660'`
I tried to subtract two date-time like the following but failed

```
x=datetime.now().time()
sleep(2)
datetime.now().time()-x
```

I got this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

Comment: How do you know it failed?

Comment: Have you tried using time.time() values, which are just seconds since 1970 as a floating point? (or in python3 better to use time.monotonic() in case daylight savings or leap seconds happen during run of program).

Comment: time.time does not give milliseconds

Comment: what if the time between the peaks is hours?

Comment: `datetime.timdelta` should meet your needs.

Comment: Well time.perfcounter_ns() is nanoseconds, so just divide by a million and should have milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

You can't subtract the `datetime.time()` objects from each other, but you can substract the `datetime.datetime()` objects to create `datetime.timedelta()` which contains the data you want.

For example

```py
x = datetime.now()
sleep(2)
(datetime.now() - x).seconds
(datetime.now() - x).microseconds
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

x = datetime.now()
time.sleep(2)
diff = datetime.now() - x
print(f"{diff.seconds}.{diff.microseconds}")  # 2.2469
```